# How I change the color of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, colors

I know how to change the background color of a JFrame, but how can I change colors within the background, so that you can see white color on a blue background, for example, or something similar?

Thanks for the help.
Here is the part of my code in which I tried it:

```
public class Malen extends JLabel {
    protected void painComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);  
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Variablen.bildschirmbreite, Variablen.bildschirmgröße);
        
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
            g.fillRect(Variablen.bildschirmbreite / 2 - 5, i * 20, 10, 10);                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, like a gradient?

Comment: You spelled the paintComponent method wrong.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *"You spelled the paintComponent method wrong."* This is why code should use the `@Override` marker when a method is intended to change the behavior of the existing method. The compiler will warn if the method name is incorrectly spelled or declares the wrong parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

public Gui() {

    JLabel label = new JLabel("white");
    // sets the label to opaque so that backround visible
    label.setOpaque(true);
    // sets the label to white
    label.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    label.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);

    frame.setTitle("White label on blue backround");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setBackground(new Color(123, 50, 250));
    panel.add(label);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Gui();
}
```

Comment: write a few words to explain how this solves the problem.